# Why Python os.path.isfile() doesn't work in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, network-drive

I don't understand why the Python function `os.path.isfile()` returns False with a file that is in a shared folder in a network drive.

I'm running the following code with Visual Studio:

```py
from os.path import isfile

path = r'\\192.158.1.38\MySharedFolder\file.txt'
print(isfile(path))
```

If I run the same code inside the command prompt, it returns True

Comment: I don't now the answer but can you try `pathlib.Path.isfile()` also?

Comment: Try reading the file through visual studio, maybe there's a permissions issue?

Comment: @buhtz Thanks but it doesn't work